# PHP generated salt in SQL-Database doesn't equal when retrieved from there

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an problem. My hashed passwords are not equal to the passwords in my database when I retrieving the SALT-Value from database.

register.php

1. Generating a random salt to add it onto the end of the password.
2. Hash the full value.
3. Insert username, hashed password and salt into database.

```
while($row){
    $SALT = random_bytes(32);
    $SALT = bin2hex($SALT);

    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM usr_accounts WHERE SALT = :SALT";
    $query_params = array(':SALT' => $SALT);
    try{
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if(empty($row)){
        break;
    }
}

for($hashnr = 0; $hashnr < 128; $hashnr++){
    $PASSWORD = hash('sha256', $_POST['PASSWORD'].$SALT);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO usr_accounts (USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT, EMAIL) VALUES (:USERNAME, :PASSWORD, :SALT, :EMAIL)";
$query_params = array(':USERNAME' => $_POST['USERNAME'], ':PASSWORD' => $PASSWORD, ':SALT' => $SALT, ':EMAIL' => $_POST['EMAIL']);
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

login.php

1. Retrieve the data (salt) from database to add it onto the end of the password.
2. Hash the full value.
3. Check if the password-values are equal.

```
$query = "SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT FROM usr_accounts WHERE USERNAME = :USERNAME";
$query_params = array(':USERNAME' => $_POST['USERNAME']);
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$login_ok = false;

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row){
    for($hashnr = 0; $hashnr < 128; $hashnr++){
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['PASSWORD'].$row['SALT']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use the built in PHP password lib. Much more secure, much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). It handles the salt for you and adds it into the hashed password. Then use password_verify() to check that a password is valid.

Also, you don't need to hash the password in a loop.

`for($hashnr = 0; $hashnr < 128; $hashnr++){
    $PASSWORD = hash('sha256', $_POST['PASSWORD'].$SALT);
}`

This is just calling hash() 128 times, getting the same result each time, and assigning it to $PASSWORD

The reason your hashed passwords aren't the same could be a character encoding issue. Make sure both PHP and SQL are set up to use the same encoding (And make that UTF8 if it's up to you). Here's a pretty good article on it [here](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for youre answer!

Now I use password_hash(), but to check a password I use an if-Statement because with password_verify() the login failed again, though right password-hash.

a other question, I hope you have an answer: BCRYPT run since 1999. Can I use other algorithms like Argon2 with password_hash()?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you post your code? As for the hashing algorithm, I'm pretty sure BCRYPT is the only one currently supported. You can use `password_hash('secret',PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` to use the default hashing algorithm. This is currently BCRYPT, but in the future, when Argon2 or something else is supported it may change